Android 12 & 13 merge all incoming notification into one area within the notification drawer
I have the problem, that my notifications on Android 12 & 13, despite being in seperate groups and channels with their own IDs get merged into one notification field inside of the notification drawer.
Notification Drawer:

In settings everything looks fine (and I also checked the incoming messages they are indeed in seperate channels and therefore also groups), yet the "Plan is active" (Location Channel) notifications and the "Order deleted" (Notifications Channel) notifications end up within the same grouping.
Settings:

How do I achieve that my sticky "Plan is active" notification is seperate from incoming "Order deleted" notifications?
I double checked all implementation for groups and channels, but it still does not seperate them.

Create Separate Notification Channels:
Define each notification channel with a unique ID. This ensures that notifications intended for different purposes are handled separately by the system.
Set Different Group Keys:
If you are using notification groups, ensure each notification group has a unique key. This is useful if you want to group some notifications together and keep others separate.
Use Different Notification IDs:
When displaying notifications, ensure you use different IDs for different notifications. Using the same ID will cause the new notification to replace the old one.

I am doing all that already. It still does not help on Android 12 and Android 13. The behavior on my older Android 8.1 phone is 100% correct.
